# Stateful Eclipse Plugin - OSGi bundle for domain model?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi, soa

I want to encapsulate my complete domain model into an eclipse plugin and expose a set of services to be consumed by other plugins. This Eclipse Plugin needs to store state because my domain model by default 
has a state at various points of time which needs to be shared across Eclipse plugins.

By default an Eclipse Plugin is same as OSGI bundle and OSGi bundles since they are based on SOA shouldn't they be stateless?

Is it a good practice to make an Eclipse Plugin services(extension points) stateful?

Is this the right approach or is there some other way like persisting state to hard disk and making the plugin stateless?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Service statelessness is a goal, not a doctrine. At the end, you as the architect must decide if a service must truly be stateless. Having said that, you connected the jumps with two hops - OSGI predates SOA and is not necessarily equivalent to it, though at the surface layer they may seem to share some similarities (modularity, service discovery, ...).

Do whatever makes sense within your framework.